# How to install cx_oracle python module for Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

first question i really had to ask on stackoverflow!
I'm trying to use cx_Oracle Python module to use SQL queries inside Google Colab. However, for cx_oracle to properly run I need Oracle instantclient installed - this is a problem as Colab works on VM. Without the client, I get error:

> "DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a
>   64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory"."

I tried to put oracle instantclient_18_5 unzipped folder into my GDrive where the Colab script is. After that, I've tried to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to it, but no matter what I do, LD_LIBRARY_PATH directory is /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64 .

```
!sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential libaio1

!python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

''' I tried a lot of code found on the internet to change this LD_LIBRARY_PATH but to no avail. Example:'''

```
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/content/gdrive/Team Drives/.../instantclient_18_5":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I would like either to install Oracle client onto google VM, or do something that it could take it from Gdrive. Whatever would work so I could use cx_oracle on Google Colab will be enough for me.

EDIT: To clarify, any way of connecting my Oracle SQL database to Google Colab python notebook will be fine! Does not have to be through cx_oracle exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

Not an ideal solution, but a work-around, which is to install the official RPM via alien, then boom! cx_python works.

1. Download the official Oracle Instant client basic lite RPM https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/193000/oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
2. Put the RPM somewhere in Gdrive
3. Mount the Gdrive

   `from google.colab import drive ROOT = "/content/blah" drive.mount(ROOT)`
4. Install alien and cx_Oracle

`!pip install cx_Oracle #install Oracle client library !apt install alien !alien -i /content/blah/foo/bar/oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm`